# mysql triggers to multiply two column values by using triggers

Tags: mysql

i have 4 columns in my table, vrms,irms,total,id.
i have created a trigger  where i want to insert the result of the trigger in another table.
  my code:
    CREATE TRIGGER `total_sum` BEFORE INSERT ON `meter5`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hourly
    SELECT vrms,irms,id,
    NEW.irms * NEW.vrms AS total;
    END
error:
not allowed to return a resultset from a trigger in mysql.

Comment: Not quite understand what you are trying to do.Could you provide more information on it. The table structure of `hourly` and what all values needs to be added from first table to the 2nd ?

Comment: i should display vrms,irms,id,total(is multiply vrms*irms) in hourly table from meter5 using triggers.

Comment: so the total is just `vrms*irms` from the last entry i.e. if you are adding 5 and 6 for vrms and irms in meter5 then the total will be added as 30 in the table `hourly` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the trigger to be `after insert` something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger total_sum after insert on meter5
for each row
begin
 insert into hourly (id,vrms,irms,total) values (new.id,new.vrms,new.irms,new.vrms*new.irms);
end ; //
delimiter ;
```